# Removing namespace prefix ns1 from xml or Soap Message

Tags: java, xml, soap, groovy

I am a beginner in programming so please bear with my lack of knowledge.

I am working on sending and receiving a soap request via `HttpsURLConnection`. The problem is, the reply from the input stream has namespace declarations and the application does not recognize these.

I take the result from the input stream as text:

```
def reply = bufferedReader.getText()
```

but I can also create a Soap Message:

```
reply = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL).createMessage(null, conn.getInputStream())
```

Both methods still give namespace prefix. But I'm not sure if I've missed something. I can manipulate both XML and SoapMessage so any pointers will help.

When I send a request using `SoapConnection.connect()`, the XML file doesn't contain the prefix. However, when I use `HttpsURLConnection`, I get these. I cannot use `SoapConnection.connect()` for other reasons though.

I have been struggling for many hours. Any help is appreciated. Please ask if you need more info.

Thanks,